# PHP var_dump(array()); returning array(0) { } array(0) { }

Tags: php, error-handling

I dont know why, but if I call `var_dump(array());`  it return the array twice

```
array(0) { } array(0) { }
```

I havent anywhere any other var_dump active

Comment: is your code snippet used twice? maybe a function or an include?

Comment: This isn't the output you'd get if you had an array that contained two empty arrays, so you must be calling var_dump() twice.

Comment: Yes, thanks guys, I got lost in the mess of code in my function @AlexHowansky

Comment: Try commenting out that line and running the script again. If you get `array(0) { }`, then you know the other one's coming from somewhere else. Otherwise, I agree it's possible this script is being `include`d or `require`d twice

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var_dump(array());
```

I get an output of, There must be something else in your code causing it to print twice.

```
array(0) { }
```